# tDenormalize erratic results

Tags: talend

Using Talend tDenormalize I'm getting erratic results.  My data is in CSV files with columns like this:

Contact ID | xx | yy | zz | Account ID | First Name | Last Name

1|x|y|z| A1 | John | Smith

2|x|y|z| A1 | Sally | Smith

3|x|y|z| B1 | Bill | Jones

4|x|y|z| B1 | Karen | Jones

I'm trying to get the tDenormalize to create :

1|x|y|z| A1%A1 | John%Sally | Smith%Smith

4|x|y|z| B1%B1 | Bill%Karen | Jones%Jones

(This contacts table I'm working on is the child table to the accounts table)

[image: Talend view]

As you can see I'm only getting a small subset of records to be "normalized"
I have also tried tDenormalizeSortedRow with similar results. It's not clear how Talend determines what rows to aggregate.  I filled the first column with the account number (overlaying the contact ID) to get the results in the Talend screen shot.  Any help would be great.

[image: Talend component details]

Answer (score 0):

After lots of tests, it seems Talend requires all other columns of data to be exactly equal to perform the tDenormalize correctly.  It would not know what to do with the other unmatched columns.  A new function to Denormalize and select other columns to "pull the first" value or last value would be a nice feature to add.(wink wink).